# Spring MVC Error 404 Bad Request Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, kotlin, jetty

> I am using **Kotlin** for developing **Spring MVC** Application.
>   I have a simple form which when i submit, I am getting **Error 404 bad Request**. I am using **Jetty server and Intellij Community Edition**.I tried debugging but since i have never debugged a web application, it wasnt that helpful.

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>frontDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>frontDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/springkotlinmvc/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**frontDispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.manya.kotlin"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**DataClasses.kt**

```
package org.manya.kotlin

data class Address (val city : String, val state : String)

data class Student ( val name : String , val age : Int, val address : Address)
```

**StudentController.kt**

```
package org.manya.kotlin

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
class StudentController
{
    //@GetMapping("/student/form")
    @GetMapping("form")
    fun studentForm() : ModelAndView{
        println("called from studentForm()")
        return ModelAndView("form")
    }

    //@PostMapping("springkotlinmvc/student/submitted")
    //@RequestMapping(value = "/student/submitted" , method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
    //@RequestMapping("/submitted")
    @PostMapping("/submitted")
    fun submitted(@ModelAttribute("student") stud : Student) : ModelAndView {
        println("called from submitted()")
        return ModelAndView("submitted")
    }
}
```

> Here the method studentForm() is perfectly getting mapped to the view(form.jsp) but the method submitted is not getting mapped.

**form.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="./submitted" method="post">
        NAME : <input id="name"/>
        AGE : <input id="age"/>
        CITY : <input id="address.city"/>
        STATE : <input id="address.state"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open browser's dev tools and track the URL that was used to send the request. Your form's `action` is `./submitted` which, probably, maps to `/student/form/submitted`, while the mapping on Spring's side is `/student/submitted`. To mitigate similar problems in future try to use `c:url` or `spring:form` tags: they are context-aware. BTW, 404 is "not found", not "bad request" that's very strange you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

check your link 404 means not found ,it may cause by not pointing to root here `./submitted` , change to `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/foo` or configuration of WEB-INF location.

```
 4×× Client Error
    400 Bad Request
    401 Unauthorized
    402 Payment Required
    403 Forbidden
    404 Not Found
    405 Method Not Allowed
    406 Not Acceptable
    407 Proxy Authentication Required
    408 Request Timeout
    409 Conflict
    410 Gone
    411 Length Required
    412 Precondition Failed
    413 Payload Too Large
    414 Request-URI Too Long
    415 Unsupported Media Type
    416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable
    417 Expectation Failed
    418 I'm a teapot
    421 Misdirected Request
    422 Unprocessable Entity
    423 Locked
    424 Failed Dependency
    426 Upgrade Required
    428 Precondition Required
    429 Too Many Requests
    431 Request Header Fields Too Large
    444 Connection Closed Without Response
    451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons
    499 Client Closed Request
```

Comment: i tried this  but it is giving me a url like this **http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/submitted** . Also the action i am giving currently is poinitng to the the correct url.

Comment: Also i would like to add that its showing **404 Bad Request** and not **404 not found" . maybe there is a difference between them .

Comment: Bad req happen in 3 case in spring : 1-server need some prop but there is not exist in back object 2-in case of type mismatching for example you are posting but server is defined to GET 3-type of data for example sending json but server consume or produce html

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake in my code and it was a small mistake but i was not aware of it because of my lack of knowledge in web domain.

> In form.jsp, in the form I was giving **id** attribute to all the input elements. I changes those to the **name** and it was working fine.